# SFMC API call to 3rd party when unsubscribing

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, subscriber, curl

We're using a 3rd party for a refer a friend service that also has a subscriber status. We'd like to link a user's unsubscribe to the 3rd party service when a user unsubscribes through the profile center. Is there anyway to add a trigger to the unsubscribe here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/wsdl-endpoint-links.htm#endpoint-links) and [Update a Subscriber](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/update_a_subscriber.htm) using the [Update Method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/updating_subscriber_attributes_using_the_update_method.htm).

1. [Create and Install a package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/install-packages.htm) to get your Client Id and Client Secret. Set the appropriate permissions.
2. Find your [appropriate WSDL and Endpoint Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/wsdl-endpoint-links.htm#endpoint-links)
3. [Update your subscriber](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/updating_subscriber_attributes_using_the_update_method.htm) using the appropriate List ID

Comment: Thank you, Jackson. I did a poor job explaining that. We need to send the call to a 3rd party service to unsubscribe the user there, we are okay on internal unsubscribe.

Figured out a potential solution though with an automation. Will be extracting a list of recently updated unsubscribes and checking/updating the 3rd party.

Thanks again!